# redirect php mysql url to other url

Tags: php, redirect

HI
i need to redirect url (http://www.mysite.com/?1 upto any numbers ?2, ?3 etc)  to other url http://www.othersite.com

Mean `www.mysite.com/?2  to www.othersite.com`
 on not access like this page www.mysite.com/?1
 any php code i need 
 reply back

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your question you're ignoring the `?n` so it's simply:

```
index.php:

<?php

header("Location: http://www.othersite.com");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (count($_GET))
    {
    header('Location:http://www.myothersite');
    }
```

Comment: Not work ... to Block this urls on random numbers http://mysite.com/?1 upto random  or to 100

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['1'])) {
  header('location: http://othersite.com');
} elseif(isset($_GET['2']) {
  header('location: http://othersite.com/otherpage');
}
//and so on
```

#### Later edit:

```
<?php

    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if(is_int($key)) {
            header('location: http://othersite.com');
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a die() statement after your header(); statements. I'm sure you know this, probably just answering the user's question directly, without the die() statement the rest of the page will continue to execute even though you are redirected.

Comment: the number are random  so any other way?

Comment: Here you go, where the key is a random number. Check the "later edit"

Comment: get also this error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (11)